# Javafx how to make a button to display and hide label

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a button to show certain text

```
roll.setOnAction(c -> {
      Label text = new Label("Hello");
      root.getChildren().add(text);             
   });
```

I want the same roll button to, when pressed another time, to "hide" or "remove" the label.

I've tried this by

```
roll.setOnAction(c -> {
      Label text = new Label("Hello");
      root.getChildren().add(text);             
   });
      roll.setOnAction(c -> {
      root.getChildren().remove(text);          
   });
```

This works only for 2 presses. I want the 3rd press to re-display the label and so on and so forth.

How can I do that? I don't want to keep adding roll.setOnAction inside itself over and over again.

Comment: I am sure I have used text.setVisible(false)  before?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: You probably should not be creating the `Label` inside of `setOnAction`.

Comment: why is that? is there an undesirable effect that might happen?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I have found to remove a label visually but still keep it in the scene graph for future use is to set its opacity to zero, or set the visibility to false.

```
text.setOpacity(0);
text.setVisibile(false);
```

Since you want different label instances every time (maybe more closely consider why), you can use a variable to do something like so

```
Label text = null;

roll.setOnAction(c -> {
    if (text == null) {
        text = new Label("Hello");
        root.getChildren().add(text);
    }
    else {
        root.getChildren().remove(text);
        text = null
    }                 
});
```

Comment: I meant to ask, how to set up my button action so that it will display and remove over and over again.

Comment: @WhitneyD Updated